# scala mutable Map withDefaultValue strange behaviour

Tags: scala

I have this example which uses a mutable `HashMap.withDefaultValue`. `withDefaultValues` provides a way to return a value even if the key does not exist, but it should not modify the collection. in any case, there is a conflicting behaviour, as `map.size` returns 0, and at the same time `map(key)` returns a value.

how is this possible?

```
import scala.collection.mutable

val map = mutable.HashMap[String, mutable.Map[Int, String]]()
          .withDefaultValue(mutable.HashMap[Int, String]())

map("id1")(2) = "three"
println(map.size)        // 0                   (expected)
println(map)             // Map()               (expected)
println(map("id1"))      // Map(2 -> three)     (unexpected)
println(map("id1")(2))   // three               (unexpected)
```

Comment: How is this unexpected? `map("id1")` uses the default value you provided.

Comment: Do you really need a mutable `Map`? I'd recommend an immutable map, or a `TrieMap`, if you need mutability in a concurrent context.

Comment: I provided an empty default value (the argument of withDefaultValue).

Comment: @reactormonk, I don't need that code at all. i am just wondering about this strange behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to factor out `defaultValue` because it's passed as a value.

```
import scala.collection.mutable

val defaultValue = mutable.HashMap[Int, String]()
val map = mutable.HashMap[String, mutable.Map[Int, String]]()
          .withDefaultValue(defaultValue)

map("id1")(2) = "three"
```

Which gives you

```
println(defaultValue)    // Map(2 -> three)
```

... which should explain the rest of the behaviour. And that's exactly why I recommend immutable data structures ;-)